# Magento 2: how to change bg Product photo

Tags: magento2

Now if we add product without photo then is displayed Basic photo with logo magento.

How to change bg to own logo where we add product without photo?

Comment: please see my answer, if have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload custom placeholder for images:

> Go to Stores-> Configuration -> Catalog open catalog section:

You will see `Product Image Placeholders` just upload your custom image

See attached image

[image]

Comment: I upload here bg product image and delete pub/static, deploy system, cache clean etc. and still is basic magento bg photo.

Comment: I am using `developer mode` and it is showing just after uploading image. If you are using `production mode`  you need to remove folder `generated`, `var`,`pub/static/` and need to `flush cache`, `deploy content`,`Flush Catalog Images` etc...

Comment: Did it work ? let me know if still have issue.